# How to get the sum of every input in this table

Tags: html, jquery

[image]

It is only showing the total of the first row, the only input area there is the partial/full qty and while everything left are came from in my database.

Here is my code jQuery code

```
$(document).on('keyup',function(){
  $("#grpoTable").each(function() {
    var qty = $('#partialqty').val();
    var price = $('#grpoprice').val();
    var total = qty*price;
    $('#grpototal').html(total);
  })
})
```

My HTML code

```
<tr id="grpoTableTr" class="grpoTable Tr">
   <td>'.$list['item'].'<input type="hidden" value="'.$list['item'].'" name="item[]"></td>
   <td>'.$list['item_code'].'<input type="hidden" value="'.$list['item_code'].'" name="item_code[]"></td>
   <td>'.$list['qty'].'<input type="hidden" value="'.$list['qty'].'" name="qty[]"></td>
   <td><input type="number" jAutoCalc="{partialqty}" id="partialqty" name="partialqty[]" class="form-control" min=1></td>
   <td>'.$list['unit_price'].'<input type="hidden" jAutoCalc="{grpoprice}" id="grpoprice" value="'.$list['unit_price'].'" name="unit_price[]"></td>
   <td><span id="grpototal" jAutoCalc="{partialqty}*{grpoprice}"></span></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="removeGRPO"><i class="uil uil-multiply"></i></button></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is that HTML code inside a loop of some kind? (`id` attributes _must_ be unique, if that is inside a loop you'll get duplicate `id`s)

Comment: IDs must be unique.  `$('#partialqty')` will always get the first ID, instead, use `$(this).find("[name=partialqty]")` (easier if you add partialqty as a class name).

Comment: I have tried this, but it is not working.